# I need some advice about dynamic programming

Tags: c++, dynamic, large-data

Here is the problem :
HaNa is a Math Maker. Initially, he has one number n. Every time he performs an action, he will remove any element x, such that x > 1, and then insert to the same position 3 number in order: floor(x/2), x mod 2, floor(x/2). He must continue this operation until he receives the list full of 0s and 1s.

Given that, the list is 1-indexed (the first index of the list is 1). Implement a function sumOfOnes to calculate the sum of the number of number 1 in the range between l and r in the list.

Note that:

- Time limit is 2 seconds
- 0 <=n< 2^50
- 0 <= r-l <= 10^5
- r >= l
- l >= 1

I use bottom_up method (dynamic programming) to solve this problem int limit time. Here is my code :

```
string hana(long long int n)
{
  string* memoize = new string[n+1];
  memoize[0] = "0";
  memoize[1] = "1";
  for(long long int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
  {
    if(i%2 == 0) memoize[i] = memoize[i/2] + "0" + memoize[i/2];
    else memoize[i] = memoize[i/2] + "1" + memoize[i/2];
  }

  return memoize[n];
}
//
long long int sumOfOnes (long long int n, long long int l, long long int r){
    string result = hana(n);
    long long int ans = 0;
    for(long long int i = l - 1; i <= r - 1; ++i)
    {
        if(result[i] == '1') ++ans;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

It works well with small input but it doesnt do the same with large input because of lack of memory!
I really need some advice about how to deal with large input.
Thanks alot!!!

Comment: This is probably a question from one of those online coding websites.  The questions from those sites are designed to have naive solutions that work for small data, but will fail for large data.  The real solution to this question more than likely does not require you to attempt to allocate terabytes of memory.  When you see constraints such as `n` ranging up to `2^50`, that is a dead giveaway that the solution requires some mathematics trick of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, besides several design flaws, you have a heavy memory leak issue, since you heap allocate a local array without proper deletion.

```
string* memoize = new string[n+1];
```

Don't do that locally this way, use an std::vector for this:

```
auto memoize = std::vector<std::string>(n + 1);
```

Further on, you are recreating the array again and again for each actual value request. This should be avoided at least for your current solving scheme with a fully initialized array, use a more 'global' storage place of the hana-array (preallocated with a maximum possible N)!

For your actual algorithmic issue, without a deeper mathematical insight here and with a feeling that the original problem was stated with more details/precision...:

You'll never be able to solve this with your current approach for n around 50 in an acceptable way.

The key is: It's a common logarithmical problem class, see binary search for instance. You should try to redesign your array access to a recursive function call access, so access to the nth element is always done via a function call and only the first two elements are actually 'concrete'. Without a deeper analysis here in the first place, complexity should already be reducable to something around O(log(n) * (r - l)). I would try to post you a solution but please ensure first, you provided the full problem description here!

Comment: Yes sir ! That's the full problem description! If you cound give me a solution on this, it would be great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I find my own solution so there is no need for you to post your solution ! I really appreciate your help! Your advice help me a lot! Thank you very much!